# PostgreSQL, update existing rows with pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump

I need to sync two PostgreSQL databases (some tables from development db to production db) sometimes.

So I came up with this script:

```
[...]
pg_dump -a -F tar -t table1 -t table2 -U user1 dbname1 | \
pg_restore -a -U user2 -d dbname2
[...]
```

The problem is that this works just for newly added rows. When I edit non-PK column I get constraint error and row isn't updated. For each dumped row I need to check if it exists in destination database (by PK) and if so delete it before INSERT/COPY.

Thanks for your advice.

(Previously posted on stackoverflow.com, but IMHO this is better place for this question).

Answer (score 1):

Proceed to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115369/do-you-source-control-your-databases.

Answer (score 0):

In any environment I've seen, this is typically not done on a table by table basis.

- There are a number of possibilities for any row: SELECT / INSERT / UPDATE / ALTER ... you would need to take care of all of these possibilities.
- Tables are not the only things that live inside databases, especially PostgreSQL databases. Sequences, functions, aggregates, views etc. can possibly all need to be copied over.

If I were in your situation, I'd dump the whole database and use it to restore a clean version.

```
pg_dump --clean --no-owner --no-privileges dbname ## other pg_dump / psql options
```

Comment: That's not possible in my case, because I have some tables that must be preserved in development and production DB (customers, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using dblink and inserting only what you need from a select?

```
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreeSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html
```